# How to convert date string to datetime in agg function during groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe, how to groupby `Item` with `max` value of `Updated Date` (as `datetime` instead of date string) *while keeping date string format in result dataframe* ?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 'Jun 12, 2019 06:16 PM'],
                  ['A', 20, 'Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM'],
                  ['B', 30, 'May 20, 2019 05:54 PM'],
                  ['B', 40, 'Apr 28, 2019 06:42 PM']],
                  columns=['Item', 'Quantity', 'Updated Date'])
>>> df
  Item  Quantity           Updated Date
0    A        10  Jun 12, 2019 06:16 PM
1    A        20  Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM
2    B        30  May 20, 2019 05:54 PM
3    B        40  Apr 28, 2019 06:42 PM
```

**Expected Output**

```py
  Item  Quantity           Updated Date
0    A        30  Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM
1    B        70  May 20, 2019 05:54 PM
```

**What I have tried**

If I put `'Updated Date': max` in the `agg()`, it would simply return the max value in alphabetical order

```py
>>> df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).agg({'Quantity': sum, 'Updated Date': max})
  Item  Quantity           Updated Date
0    A        30  Jun 12, 2019 06:16 PM   # expected to be Jul 26
1    B        70  May 20, 2019 05:54 PM
```

If I apply `pd.to_datetime()` it gives me a closer result but the date string format is distorted

```py
df['Updated Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Updated Date'])
df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).agg({'Quantity': sum, 'Updated Date': max})
  Item  Quantity        Updated Date
0    A        30 2019-07-26 10:56:00
1    B        70 2019-05-20 17:54:00
```

Is it possible to apply `pd.to_datetime()` only during `groupby` ?  The challenge here is datetime format is not guaranteed to be '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p' while I want to keep the date string as is in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `datetime` just as reference for your comparisons.

```
g = (df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['Updated Date']))
    .groupby('Item')
    .agg({'Quantity': 'sum', 'date': 'idxmax'}))

g['Updated Date'] = df.loc[g.date, 'Updated Date'].tolist()
```

---

```
      Quantity           Updated Date
Item                                 
A           30  Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM
B           70  May 20, 2019 05:54 PM
```

Comment: thanks @rafaelc, think we have to drop `'date'` column in the end: `g.drop(columns=['date'], inplace=True)`

Comment: rafaelc can you please help me with this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252632/perform-pandas-aggregation-whiles-keeping-the-date-column-intact

Answer (score 1):

Convert to datetime and use `idxmax` is the way to go. You don't need to change your dataframe, for example:

```
# these are the index of the max dates
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Updated Date']).groupby(df['Item']).idxmax()

(df.groupby('Item')[['Quantity']].sum()        # get the sum of quantity
   .merge(df.loc[s, ['Item','Updated Date']],  # merge with the original rows for dates
          on='Item'                            # on the Item of course
          )
)
```

Output:

```
  Item  Quantity           Updated Date
0    A        30  Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM
1    B        70  May 20, 2019 05:54 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using lambda like below

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 'Jun 12, 2019 06:16 PM'],
                  ['A', 20, 'Jul 26, 2019 10:56 AM'],
                  ['B', 30, 'May 20, 2019 05:54 PM'],
                  ['B', 40, 'Apr 28, 2019 06:42 PM']],
                  columns=['Item', 'Quantity', 'Updated Date'])

df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).agg({'Quantity': sum, 'Updated Date': lambda g: g.loc[pd.to_datetime(df["Updated Date"]).idxmax()]})
```

or not using apply function like

```py
df["Updated Date 2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Updated Date"])
result = df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).agg({'Quantity': sum, 'Updated Date 2': "idxmax"})
result["Updated Date"] = df["Updated Date"].loc[result["Updated Date 2"]].values
result.drop(columns="Updated Date 2", inplace=True)
result
```

Comment: as mentioned in the question, I want to keep the date string as is in the result dataframe